# Domains added with WHM don't serve the correct page

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

For example when I add

```
example.com
```

I'd have to do

```
example.com/~example/
```

To see my files or else it will show the page that it would if I had just gone to IP of the server (the default page). Why is this happening and how do I fix it? This is a dedicated server I have root access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few questions:

1. Have you verified dns has been updated to point to the correct ip?
2. Have you ran /scripts/fixetchosts in the cPanel/WHM servers shell?
3. Have you ran /scripts/fixvaliases in the cPanel/WHM servers shell?

This could also be due to your own local dns being cached... are you seeing the generic cPanel page ?

Comment: I fixed the IPs for both of them but now it shows a blank directory (index of / with no files) but if I do `example.com/~example` it shows the correct directory/files